# Why my datepicker is not functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'd like to add a datepicker to my code to pick the birth date of user, however, even though I have embed the jquery and jquery-ui, the datepicker is not functioning and showed up...

Here is my code (I am using laravel 5.2)

here is the layout:

```
<!--
Retrospect by TEMPLATED
templated.co @templatedco
Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)-->
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/index.css')}}" />
<script src="{{asset('jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css')}}">
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
```

```
<!-- Header -->
    <header id="header" class="skel-layers-fixed">
        <h1><a href="/">@yield('header')</a></h1>
        <a href="#nav">Menu</a>
    </header>

<!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav">
        <!-- Authentication Links -->
        @if (Auth::guard('web')->guest())
            <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('/')}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('assessment')}}">assessment</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="email">Kirim Email</a></li> -->
            </ul>
        @else
           <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('/')}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('assessment')}}">assessment</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('user/edit')}}">Edit Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('user/pasien')}}">Edit Pasien</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('logout')}}">Logout</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="email">Kirim Email</a></li> -->
            </ul>
        @endif
    </nav>

@yield('content')
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="inner">
            <ul class="icons">
                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook">
                    <span class="label">Facebook</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter">
                    <span class="label">Twitter</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram">
                    <span class="label">Instagram</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-linkedin">
                    <span class="label">LinkedIn</span>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                <a href="faq">FAQ</a> | <a href="terms">Terms & Conditions</a>
            </p>
            <ul class="copyright">
                <li>&copy; PT. Digital Media Laboratorindo.</li>
                <li>Images: <a href="http://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a>.</li>
                <li>Design: <a href="http://templated.co">TEMPLATED</a>.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{asset('assets/js/skel.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('assets/js/util.js')}}"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="{{asset('assets/js/index.js')}}"></script>
```

and here is my own form...

```
    @extends('master.nonindex')

@section('title')
Halaman Edit Pasien
@endsection

@section('header')
Edit Pasien
@endsection

@section('content')
<script src="{{asset('jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
      //home service
       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        altField: '.datepicker1',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: '+1d',
        maxDate: '+14d'
    });
</script>
<!-- Main -->
            <section id="main" class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- Form -->
                        <section>
                        @foreach($pasien as $p)
                            <h3>Edit Pasien {{$p->nama_panggilan}}</h3>
                            <form method="post" action="{{URL::to('updatePasien')}}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="nama_panggilan" value="{{$p->nama_panggilan}}">
                                <div class="row uniform 50%">
                                    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    Nama depan:
                                        <input type="text" name="nama_depan" id="name" value="{{$p->nama_depan}}" placeholder="Nama Depan" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    Nama belakang:
                                        <input type="text" name="nama_belakang" id="email" value="{{$p->nama_belakang}}" placeholder="Nama Belakang" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    No. KTP:
                                        <input type="text" name="ktp" value="{{$p->no_ktp}}" placeholder="Nomor KTP Anda">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    Alamat:
                                        <input type="text" name="alamat" value="{{$p->alamat}}" placeholder="Tuliskan Alamat Anda">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    Tanggal lahir:
                                        <input type="text" name="tanggal_lahir" value="{{$p->tanggal_lahir}}" placeholder="Tanggal Lahir" class="datepicker1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        Agama: <br>
                                            <select name="agama" id="category">
                                                <option value="{{$p -> agama}}">{{$p -> agama}}</option>
                                                <option value="Kristen Protestan">Kristen Protestan</option>
                                                <option value="Kristen Katolik">Kristen Katolik</option>
                                                <option value="Islam">Islam</option>
                                                <option value="Konghucu">Konghucu</option>
                                                <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
                                                <option value="Budha">Budha</option>
                                            </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                            Jenis Kelamin: <br>
                                            @if($p->jenis_kelamin=='L')
                                            <select name="jenis_kelamin" id="category">
                                                <option value="L" selected>Laki-laki</option>
                                                <option value="P">Perempuan</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @elseif($p->jenis_kelamin=='P')
                                            <select name="jenis_kelamin" id="category">
                                                <option value="L">Laki-laki</option>
                                                <option value="P" selected>Perempuan</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @else
                                            <select name="jenis_kelamin" id="category">
                                                <option value="" selected>Jenis Kelamin Anda</option>
                                                <option value="L">Laki-laki</option>
                                                <option value="P" >Perempuan</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    TB:
                                        <input type="text" name="tb" id="name" value="{{$p->tb}}" placeholder="TB Anda" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    BB:
                                        <input type="text" name="bb" id="email" value="{{$p->bb}}" placeholder="BB Anda" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        Golongan Darah: <br>
                                            <select name="goldar" id="category">
                                                <option value="{{$p -> gol_darah}}">{{$p -> gol_darah}}</option>
                                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                                <option value="AB">AB</option>
                                                <option value="O">O</option>
                                            </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        Status Perkawinan: <br>
                                            <select name="status_perkawinan" id="category">
                                                <option value="{{$p -> status_perkawinan}}">{{$p -> status_perkawinan}}</option>
                                                <option value="1">Kawin</option>
                                                <option value="2">Belum Kawin</option>
                                            </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    Apakah anda mempunyai Alergi?
                                        <input type="text" name="alergi" value="{{$p->alergi}}" placeholder="Apakah anda mempunyai Alergi">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input type="submit" value="Update" class="special" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            @endforeach
                        </section>
                </div>
            </section>
@endsection
```

Thank you for your help...

UPDATE:

here is the code rayon

```
    @extends('master.nonindex')

@section('title')
Halaman Edit Pasien
@endsection

@section('header')
Edit Pasien
@endsection

@section('content')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
      //home service
       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        altField: '.datepicker1',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: '+1d',
        maxDate: '+14d'
    });
    });

</script>
<!-- Main -->
            <section id="main" class="wrapper">
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- Form -->
                        <section>
                        @foreach($pasien as $p)
                            <h3>Edit Pasien {{$p->nama_panggilan}}</h3>
                            <form method="post" action="{{URL::to('updatePasien')}}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="nama_panggilan" value="{{$p->nama_panggilan}}">
                                <div class="row uniform 50%">
                                    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    Nama depan:
                                        <input type="text" name="nama_depan" id="name" value="{{$p->nama_depan}}" placeholder="Nama Depan" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    Nama belakang:
                                        <input type="text" name="nama_belakang" id="email" value="{{$p->nama_belakang}}" placeholder="Nama Belakang" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    No. KTP:
                                        <input type="text" name="ktp" value="{{$p->no_ktp}}" placeholder="Nomor KTP Anda">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    Alamat:
                                        <input type="text" name="alamat" value="{{$p->alamat}}" placeholder="Tuliskan Alamat Anda">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    Tanggal lahir:
                                        <input type="text" name="tanggal_lahir" value="{{$p->tanggal_lahir}}" placeholder="Tanggal Lahir" class="datepicker1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        Agama: <br>
                                            <select name="agama" id="category">
                                                <option value="{{$p -> agama}}">{{$p -> agama}}</option>
                                                <option value="Kristen Protestan">Kristen Protestan</option>
                                                <option value="Kristen Katolik">Kristen Katolik</option>
                                                <option value="Islam">Islam</option>
                                                <option value="Konghucu">Konghucu</option>
                                                <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
                                                <option value="Budha">Budha</option>
                                            </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                            Jenis Kelamin: <br>
                                            @if($p->jenis_kelamin=='L')
                                            <select name="jenis_kelamin" id="category">
                                                <option value="L" selected>Laki-laki</option>
                                                <option value="P">Perempuan</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @elseif($p->jenis_kelamin=='P')
                                            <select name="jenis_kelamin" id="category">
                                                <option value="L">Laki-laki</option>
                                                <option value="P" selected>Perempuan</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @else
                                            <select name="jenis_kelamin" id="category">
                                                <option value="" selected>Jenis Kelamin Anda</option>
                                                <option value="L">Laki-laki</option>
                                                <option value="P" >Perempuan</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    TB:
                                        <input type="text" name="tb" id="name" value="{{$p->tb}}" placeholder="TB Anda" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                                    BB:
                                        <input type="text" name="bb" id="email" value="{{$p->bb}}" placeholder="BB Anda" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        Golongan Darah: <br>
                                            <select name="goldar" id="category">
                                                <option value="{{$p -> gol_darah}}">{{$p -> gol_darah}}</option>
                                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                                <option value="AB">AB</option>
                                                <option value="O">O</option>
                                            </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        Status Perkawinan: <br>
                                            <select name="status_perkawinan" id="category">
                                                <option value="{{$p -> status_perkawinan}}">{{$p -> status_perkawinan}}</option>
                                                <option value="1">Kawin</option>
                                                <option value="2">Belum Kawin</option>
                                            </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                    Apakah anda mempunyai Alergi?
                                        <input type="text" name="alergi" value="{{$p->alergi}}" placeholder="Apakah anda mempunyai Alergi">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input type="submit" value="Update" class="special" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            @endforeach
                        </section>
                </div>
            </section>

            <script src="{{asset('jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Place your `script` tag as a last child of `body` or listen `ready` event

Comment: @Rayon Thanks for the answer, could you mind to tell me what "last child of body" or using ready? Do you mean $(document).ready?

Comment: Yes, try `$(document).ready`

Comment: please check the recent update @Rayon

Comment: Hi @Rayon thanks, document ready is helping me a lot...

Comment: I hope that solves the issue...

Answer (score 0):

You might want check your client side errors first on the browser. That will give you a clear picture of "what exactly is wrong?".

Comment: @Rayon I know this does not qualify as an answer but i dont have enough reputation to comment on your question. :)

Comment: [_Read this_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)